# Find ".git" dirs but ignore some paths; or how does `find -not` work

Tags: find

I can't figure out how the find -not works.

Let's say that I would like to locate all .git dirs in the tree.

```
find -type d -iname .git
```

No problems, but then let's say that I have some dirs that I don't like to be included, in question they can be called "old" and "backup".

I could pipe to grep -v and that will work just fine.

```
find -type d -iname .git | grep -v old | grep -v backup
```

But when I browsed the man page for find I noticed that there is a -not, but I can't figure out how it is intended to work.

I tried like this, but he does not exclude the old dir.

```
find -type d -iname .git -not -iname old
```

How does the find -not work? Can I use it for this find of problem?

Comment: It would be good to specify what exactly you try to find - do you really want to exclude and include what the second example does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find has a little bit of sophistication to deal with this case:

> If the expression contains no actions other than `-prune`, `-print` is performed on all files for which the expression is true.

So explicitly print just the parts you want:

```
find -type d \( -iname old -prune -o -iname backup -prune -o -iname .git -print \)
```

avoids searching the old and backup trees at all.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `-prune` option of `find`,
it's really pretty tricky. It requires to use `-path` instead of `-name` too.

I think you want to use this:

```
find . -type d \( -path '*/old' -prune -o -iname '.git' -print \)
```

The effect of the `-not` is implemented by

- matching old "old", and the donig nothing
- or (using option -o)
- matching ".git" and printing the name
- or (by default)
- doing nothing (because the normal default action of find, an implicit `-print` at the end of the command line, is disabled, if `-print` is used already)

I recognize that other variants, while *looking* more complicated on the command line, may be easier to use, for example because the use of a different logic expression, and the changing of the default action.
On the other hand, the variants involving `-prune` are easier to generalize for more complex cases, when other syntax will be hard to handle just because it gets too long to read.

Comment: `-path '*/old'` is the same as `-name old`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Oh, I thought in relation to -prune, it's explicitly needed to match the whole path. But that may apply only for some other case...

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Re your edit: leaving out the dir "." was not intended, of course. And yes, looks like it did not check the '.git' to be a directory, I assume; Thanks!

Comment: @StephaneChazelas regarding whether `-path` is needed instead of `-name` with `-prune`, I was thinking of the normal case where we want to exclude a certain directory, not all, recursively, that are named "old".

Answer (score 2):

You could exclude the directories by specifying `-path`:

```
find . -type d \( -iname .git ! -path "*/old/*" ! -path "*/backup/*" \)
```

Note that `-not` in GNU `find` is the same as `!` but is not POSIX compliant.

Quoting from `man find`:

```
   ! expr True  if  expr  is false.  This character will also usually need
          protection from interpretation by the shell.

   -not expr
          Same as ! expr, but not POSIX compliant.
```

Comment: That still descends into the `old` directories, you may want to use `-prune` here to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> find -type d -iname .git -not -iname old
> ```

This matches directories which are called `.git` and not called `old`. Since a directory which is called `.git` cannot be called `old`, the `-not -iname old` part can be removed without changing the meaning of the command.

`-not` says “don't match”, but not “don't recurse into”. There's a different way to say “don't recurse into”: it's an action called `-prune`. The following command means “traverse all directories recursively (`find`), but stop at directories called `old` (`-iname old -prune`), and print directories called `.git`”:

```
find -iname old -prune -o -type d -iname .git -print
```

This is parsed as `( -iname old -prune ) -o ( -type d -iname .git -print )`. Find is told to look for files that meet the conditions `-iname old` or (`-o`) `-type d -iname .git`. When a file meets the first condition, the action `-prune` (prune from the traversed tree, i.e. don't recurse) is executed. When a file meets the second condition, the action `-print` is executed. As printing is the default action, you can omit `-print`.